# Algorithmic problem, how to find the number of pixels bordered by an angle code in python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, angle

A newbie is here and I'm working on python/opencv about spatial relations problem, I need to find from a point P the number of white pixels in the range (0,alpha), do you have an idea how to do it or is there any tool.
Here two images to describe well my question
The original binary image I've
[image]

From a given point p, I need to compute how much white pixels are inside the shape created by the angle
[image]

If there is any algorithmic solution I can implement or any opencv function tell me please.

Comment: You could simply create a contour in the shape of the triangle, then draw it in a new boolean mask. Once you have that you can invert it and use it to set all the non-triangle pixels in a copy of your image to zero. Then sum up the left-over non-zero pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lol, @Fiver got to it before I could finish coding up the example. Well, here's what I did to get that.

I created a set of three points (the original point, a point far off to the right, and a rotate point that matched the given angle).

I used those three points to draw two lines. I used copyMakeBorder to create a square edge outside of the image to create a closed shape with the lines I drew. I then used findContours and I know that I'm going to get three contours (except when angle == 0, but let's ignore that).

The first contour will be the whole rectangle because I chose the tree hierarchy (it's the parent). Of the two children contours I separate them into big and small and choose which one I want make a mask with based on the given angle.

Marked Image

[image]

Just the mask

[image]

Note: This method will fail when angle == 0 or abs(angle) == 180. When angle == 0 there are only two contours so the code will crash. When abs(angle) == 180 it'll arbitrarily choose one of the contours.

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

# turns a list into an int tuple
def tup(point):
    return (int(point[0]), int(point[1]));

# translate a point
def translate2D(point, target, sign):
    point[0] += target[0] * sign;
    point[1] += target[1] * sign;

# rotate a point
def rotate2D(point, deg):
    # unpack
    x, y = point;
    rads = math.radians(deg);

    # trig
    rcos = math.cos(rads);
    rsin = math.sin(rads);

    # rotate
    point[0] = x * rcos - y * rsin;
    point[1] = x * rsin + y * rcos;

# load image
img = cv2.imread("blub.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# point and angle
point = [100, 150];
angle = -60; # negative is counter-clockwise

# create projection
xproj = [point[0] + img.shape[1], point[1]];
rot = xproj[:];
translate2D(rot, point, -1);
rotate2D(rot, angle);
translate2D(rot, point, 1);

# create copy and draw lines
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8);
mask = cv2.line(mask, tup(point), tup(xproj), (255), 1);
mask = cv2.line(mask, tup(point), tup(rot), (255), 1);
border = 1;
mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, border, border, border, border, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, (255));

# contours (should always be 3 unless 0 degrees)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
print(len(contours));

# compare two children contours
one, two = contours[1:];
if cv2.contourArea(one) > cv2.contourArea(two):
    big = one;
    small = two;
else:
    big = two;
    small = one;

# check which one we should draw
if abs(angle) >= 180:
    con = small;
else:
    con = big;
cv2.drawContours(gray, [con], -1, (0), -1);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 100, 255);

# draw visual
img[mask == 255] = (0,0,200);
img = cv2.line(img, tup(point), tup(xproj), (0,255,0), 1);
img = cv2.line(img, tup(point), tup(rot), (0,255,0), 1);

# count
print("White Pixels: " + str(np.count_nonzero(mask)));

# show
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.imshow("blub", img);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Edit:

If you want to generalize this to the case of two points + an angle (not just projecting along the x-axis) we can use the same algorithm, but just replace the x-projection point with a projected point along the <p2 - p1> vector.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

# extends a p2 along its line
def extend(p1, p2, proj_length):
    # get unit vector
    dx = p2[0] - p1[0];
    dy = p2[1] - p1[1];
    dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    dx /= dist;
    dy /= dist;

    # project
    dx *= proj_length;
    dy *= proj_length;
    return [dx, dy];

# turns a list into an int tuple
def tup(point):
    return (int(point[0]), int(point[1]));

# translate a point
def translate2D(point, target, sign):
    point[0] += target[0] * sign;
    point[1] += target[1] * sign;

# rotate a point
def rotate2D(point, deg):
    # unpack
    x, y = point;
    rads = math.radians(deg);

    # trig
    rcos = math.cos(rads);
    rsin = math.sin(rads);

    # rotate
    point[0] = x * rcos - y * rsin;
    point[1] = x * rsin + y * rcos;

# load image
img = cv2.imread("blub.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# get image resolution
h, w = img.shape[:2];

# point and angle
point = [100, 150];
angle = -60; # negative is counter-clockwise

# second point
p2 = [150, 90];

# create projection
# xproj = [point[0] + img.shape[1], point[1]];
projection = extend(point, p2, h * w);
rot = projection[:];
translate2D(rot, point, -1);
rotate2D(rot, angle);
translate2D(rot, point, 1);

# create copy and draw lines
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8);
mask = cv2.line(mask, tup(point), tup(projection), (255), 1);
mask = cv2.line(mask, tup(point), tup(rot), (255), 1);
border = 1;
mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, border, border, border, border, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, (255));

# contours (should always be 3 unless 0 degrees)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
print(len(contours));

# compare two children contours
one, two = contours[1:];
if cv2.contourArea(one) > cv2.contourArea(two):
    big = one;
    small = two;
else:
    big = two;
    small = one;

# check which one we should draw
if abs(angle) >= 180:
    con = small;
else:
    con = big;
cv2.drawContours(gray, [con], -1, (0), -1);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 100, 255);

# draw visual
img[mask == 255] = (0,0,200);
cv2.line(img, tup(point), tup(projection), (0,255,0), 1);
cv2.line(img, tup(point), tup(rot), (0,255,0), 1);
cv2.circle(img, tup(point), 3, (255,255,0), -1);
cv2.circle(img, tup(p2), 3, (255,255,0), -1);

# count
print("White Pixels: " + str(np.count_nonzero(mask)));

# show
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.imshow("blub", img);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: what if for example i want to extend the code so he can work for any given angle, like between any given 3 points making an angle p1p0p2,  [even if  p0.x != p1..x!=p2.x]

Comment: the code should work fine for that. Replace the x projection point with whatever you want. The rotation will still do its job and everything else should continue to work (with the same angle restrictions)

Comment: oh, but you still need to project the line from p1 to p2 out beyond the ends of the image